# Can I put newborn platies with neon tetras?

Tags: aquarium, fish, community-aquarium

I have 4 newborn platy fry. Can I put them with neon tetras in one aquarium?

[image]

Comment: Like Henders mentioned, they can indeed chase & eat the fry. I also have tetra's & platyes, but I'm actually happy that they do. Platy's breed fast, and before you know it you'll have to many. So unless you really want to breed & sell the platy's I would just let nature handle it.

Answer (score 7):

Neon tetras will attempt to eat these. I've kept neon tetras with shrimp and they would often pursue the baby shrimp. Luckily for the shrimp, they're pretty fast and hard to see so the fish would rarely get them.

Whilst the fry will attempt to hide or run away continuously from the tetras if chased, it will probably either end with the fry being too stressed (because of all the chasing) or they will be eaten. If you have a heavily planted tank then you may get away with it because there is much more cover to hide in but there is a risk.

I would put them into a [fry tank](https://www.amazon.co.uk/SENZEAL-Isolation-functional-Breeding-Incubator/dp/B073P47WBL/ref=sr_1_1?s=pet-supplies&ie=UTF8&qid=1520848972&sr=1-1&keywords=fry+tank&dpID=61Ue4pb5ygL&preST=_SY300_QL70_&dpSrc=srch) which sits in the same tank to allow the water to flow through it but the fry is unable to get out. (The one linked actually looks a  bit small so you may wish to find another). This means the fry will grow larger and then you can eventually let them free into the main tank with no acclimatisation required.